# Edit labels to a timeline (tikz)

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overleaf

[image: Pic 1 target]

Can somebody help me to add the labels: "1st period", "2nd period",..., "n^th period" similar to the top picture (betwwen lines) to the timeline showed in the bottom picture, and remove the "1", "2", "3", ...,"n-1", "n".

[image: Pic 2]

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={table,dvipsnames},t]{beamer}

\subsection{Timeline}

\begin{frame}{Timeline}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[line width=1pt] (0,0) -- node[below=1mm,pos=0.6,scale=2] {$\cdots$} (10,0)node[right=1mm]{(periods)};
  \foreach \x/\y in {0/0}{
    \draw[line width=1pt] (\x,-2mm)node[below](\x){\strut\y} -- (\x,2mm)node[above]{};
    }
  \foreach \x/\y in {1/1,2/2,3/3,9/$n-1$,10/$n$}{
    \draw[line width=1pt] (\x,-2mm)node[below](\x){\strut\y} -- (\x,2mm)node[above]{};
    }
    \draw[-latex] (0,-7mm) -- +(0,-10mm)node[below]{$PV_{N\rvert I/Y}$};
    \draw[-latex] (10,-7mm) -- +(0,-10mm)node[below]{$FV_{N\rvert I/Y}$};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{frame}
```

Comment: I want to conserve the PV and FV labels at the beginning of the first period and end of the n^th period respectively.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and change your title to something meaningful.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can get you started:

```
\documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[line width=1pt] (0,0) -- node[below=4mm, pos=0.6] {$\cdots$} (10,0) node[right=1mm] {(periods)};
  \foreach \x in {0,...,3,9,10} {
    \draw[line width=1pt] (\x,-2mm) -- (\x,2mm);
  }
  \foreach \x/\y in {
        1/1\textsuperscript{st},
        2/2\textsuperscript{nd},
        3/3\textsuperscript{rd},
        10/$n$\textsuperscript{th}} {
    \draw[decorate, decoration={brace, mirror}] ([xshift=1pt]{\x-1},-2.75mm) -- ([xshift=-1pt]\x,-2.75mm) node[midway, below=1mm, align=center, font=\footnotesize] {\y \\ period};
  }
  \draw[-latex] (0,-5mm) -- +(0,-10mm) node[below] {$PV_{N\rvert I/Y}$};
  \draw[-latex] (10,-5mm) -- +(0,-10mm) node[below] {$FV_{N\rvert I/Y}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]